# How to change URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

Current I have URL *www.site.com/mauritius/className/function/id*.
I have managed to remove *index.php* using .htaccess.

Now I want to remove function segment from URL. I want to make above URL 
*www.site.com/mauritius/className/id*.
Just don't want 'function' in URL for only one function.

Comment: [CodeIgniter routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html).

Comment: I want to achieve functionality of above URL and show different URL.
Will I be able to do that using routing?

Comment: Okay, you did not read it. Figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your route in config/routes.php

```
$route['alias'] = 'controller/method';
```

or rewrite url using .htaccess

i am not check this but you can try like

```
RewriteRule ^controller/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/?$ controller/function/$1 [L,QSA]
```

For more :- http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: I don't want to load different method. Want to achieve same functionality but just want to rewrite URL. Want to remove method from URL functionality will be same as defined in same method.

Comment: Can you please tell me what to write in .htaccess to remove it. Thank you